# select distinct and one another column of the id

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a table with multiple columns but I need only 2.

```sql
select id, department from tbl
```

If I want to use `distinct`, how do I do that?
This is not working:

```sql
select id, distinct department from tbl
```

Comment: You have not provided sufficient information for an answer. You should post some sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following to get distinct rows:

```
select distinct id, department 
from tbl
```

However, you can't simply get distinct departments if some departments have multiple Id's - you need to figure out which of the multiple Id's you want (max? min? something else?).

Comment: i want the distinct to be only for the department and that the rest columns i will need will be avilable for using later so i need to get the id column

Comment: @Y.G.J - Does each department have just one Id associated with it, or multiple?

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with this answer, it is the best that can be done given the lack of information from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  * FROM Table c1
 WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table c2
    WHERE c1.department = c2.department)
```

Answer (score 3):

What the question is asking exactly is unclear, but one scenario could be that you want to get all rows, except that a particular column should only contain unique values, and you don't mind which rows are discarded to achieve this.

In SQL Server this can be achieved with the following:

```sql
SELECT id, department FROM tbl WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY department
)
```

Where `id` is unique for each row, `department` is the column which should be distinct, and `tbl` is the table name.

If you want to only perform this check on non-NULL values (so all NULL values for `department` are still returned), this can be tweaked to:

```sql
SELECT id, department FROM tbl WHERE department IS NULL OR id IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY department
)
```

Note that this will run very slowly, so is only feasible for tables with a small number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` needs to operate on all of the columns for the same reason why `GROUP BY` needs to include all the columns (that don't have aggregate functions operate on them) and that is that in the case you want to apply DISTINCT to the following resultset

```
id    department
----------------
1     one
2     one
3     one
4     two
```

then even if `SELECT id, DISTINCT department FROM table_name` was allowed (and it is in some databases; for example mysql can do group by department and not include id in the GROUP BY) then you would end up with undefined situation:

```
id    department
----------------
?     one
4     two
```

What should go instead of `?` - 1, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

The presented statement below assumes select the first id where matches the distinct value

```
select distinct (select top 1 id from tbl t2 where t1.department= t2.department) as id, department from tbl t1
```

Answer (score -1):

Would a group by fix your problem?

```
select id, department from tbl group by id
```

Comment: no, not in msaccess (or databases other than mysql). the suggested SQL throws an error in databases that follow SQL standard in regards to GORUP BY.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write: select id, department from tbl group by id, department